# How to iterate through multi-nested JSON Object for dropdown function in Angular 6?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nested

I am working in Angular 6.0 and I have ran into the issue of using HttpClient to iterate through my JSON data I am reading in from a local file in my assets folder.

Here is my JSON Data

```
[{
    "configKey": [{
        "user1": [{
            "subconfig": [{
                "name": "program Id",
                "type": "String"
            }, {
                "name": "brand ID",
                "type": "String"
            }]

        }],
        "user2": {
            "subconfig": [{
                "name": "program Id",
                "type": "String"
            }, {
                "name": "brand ID",
                "type": "String"
            }]
        },

        "user3": {
            "subconfig": [{
                "name": "program Id",
                "type": "String"
            }, {
                "name": "brand ID",
                "type": "String"
            }]
        }
    }]
}]
```

Here is my current code in the component ts file

```
  rule:Array<any> =[];

  loadinfo(){
    this.http.get<any[]>("assets/test.json")
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.rule = data;
    })
  }
```

Here's what I have in the HTML File

```
  <label>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let og of rule">
        {{og.configKey}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
```

In my expected end goal, I should be able to populate a dropdown list based on a previous selection. (eg. I select user1, the list should populate with the 'names' in it's user tree in the JSON). However, I have not gotten to this part and would just like help with simply populating a dropdown list with names from my JSON tree.

From my previous research, I understand that HttpClient only returns Objects and that *ngFor only works on arrays. I have tried to change the object to an array, but my result is only another error that states that ngFor can only iterate through objects. Is there a way to change my entire nested JSON object to Array?

For what it's worth, here is my JSON Data in console
[Console JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogXNj.png)

How would I go about making my data iterable by *ngFor and how would I navigate to the names? I would assume in the html it would be something like this? :

```
//TEST CODE????

  <label>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let og of rule">
        {{og.configKey.user1.subconfig.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate objects by `keyvalue` pipe. (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

You can do it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let config of res | keyvalue">
  <div>{{config.key}}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let users of config.value">
    <div *ngFor="let user of users | keyvalue">
      <div>{{user.key}}</div>
      <div *ngFor="let subcfgs of user.value | keyvalue">
        <div>{{subcfgs.key}}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let subcfg of subcfgs.value">
          <div>name: {{subcfg.name}}</div>
          <div>type: {{subcfg.type}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ph76ya

I have edited your JSON.

Comment: Hey Thanks! This is really helpful! I updated my angular to be able to use the KeyValue Pipe and it's working. I have another question if you don't mind helping me out. Is there a specific way I can iterate to a specific user? Say I only want to show the dropdown name and type for a specific user. How would I iterate to that specific user? I've tried changing the "users" to something like "users.user1" but that didn't seem to work... Thanks again!

Comment: How about using `*ngIf` to show specific user? like `*ngIf="user.key === 'specificUserName'"`

Comment: @zmag How can this nested value be populated in a dropdown/select? For example, list of name.